# Search and filter through deep json value with Angular $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

This is a sample Json that I am using to render in my html using Angular's ng-repeat directive.

```
[
  {
    "id": "10.0.0.208",
    "ip_address": "10.0.0.208",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "--invalid secret key--",
    "ports": [
      8056,
      8057
    ],
    "installations": 2,
    "created": "2016-07-15 17:41:36",
    "wanpipe": {
      "wp1": {
        "port": 8056,
        "physical": true,
        "signalling": true,
        "outgoing": true,
        "hangup_cause": "NORMAL_CLEARING",
        "outgoing_caller_id": "1409716078"
      },
      "wp2": {
        "port": 8056,
        "physical": true,
        "signalling": true,
        "outgoing": true,
        "hangup_cause": "NORMAL_CLEARING",
        "outgoing_caller_id": "1409716077"
      },
      "wp3": {
        "port": 8056,
        "physical": true,
        "signalling": true,
        "outgoing": true,
        "hangup_cause": NORMAL_CLEARING","outgoing_caller_id":"1409716077"
  }
]
```

I made a search bar in HTML by calling an angular filter on the attribute ip_address, which is as follows. It works and returns to me a filtered array called pagedItems which I can reiterate again using ng-repeat.

```
$scope.figureOutIPToDisplay = function(searchIP) {
        console.log(searchIP);
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.json.json, {
            ip_address : $scope.searchIP
        });

        $scope.pagedItems = $scope.filteredItems;
        console.log($scope.pagedItems);

    };
```

The following is the HTML code,

```
<div class="row"  ng-repeat=" init in pagedItems  ">
 <div ng-repeat="(key,wanpipe) in init.wanpipe" class=" col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-4  ">
                                        <button popover-trigger="focus" uib-popover-template="templateUrl" ng-if="wanpipe.physical==true"type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >{{key}}</button>

                                        <button popover-trigger="focus"  uib-popover-template="templateUrl" ng-if="wanpipe.physical==false" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">{{key}}</button>

                                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
                                            <div class="row ipAddressdetails">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></span> Port: {{wanpipe.port}}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row ipAddressdetails">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Physical: {{wanpipe.physical}}
                                                </div>
</div>
```

However in the aforementioned Json, I also tried to filter it on the basis of the port attribute which is a part of the wanpipe object, which in turn consists of other objects, namely wp1, wp2,wp3, etc having the port attribute. 
I have tried a lot of things to make it work but have failed miserable, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do deep filter, you use `$` sign instead of the actual property name. So if you want to deep search on all properties in your object you can use

**[From angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):**

> Note that a named property will match properties on the same level
>   only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same
>   level or deeper. E.g. an array item like {name: {first: 'John', last:
>   'Doe'}} will not be matched by {name: 'John'}, but will be matched by
>   {$: 'John'}

```
 $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.json.json, {
            $: $scope.searchIP
        });
```

> However in the aforementioned Json, I also tried to filter it on the
>   basis of the port attribute which is a part of the wanpipe object,
>   which in turn consists of other objects, namely wp1, wp2,wp3, etc
>   having the port attribute.

This might work for your scenario. This will look into only `wanpipe` property.

```
 $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.json.json, {
            wanpipe: {$: $scope.searchIP} 
        });
```